# Displaying Name Input From Form

Tags: javascript, html, input, output

I'm trying to figure out how to get JavaScript to display values entered into a form element.

I may be doing this wrong from the outset and this is not the standard way to do it but here is what I'm working with.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    First name:
    <input type= "text" id="firstname" name="firstname"> <br> <br>
        Last name: <input type= "text" id="lastname" name="lastname" <br> 
        <br> <br>
    <input type = "submit" value="submit">      
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>

    function getElementById("firstname") {
        var userName = document.getElementById("firstname")
        document.write("Hello, " + userName);
</script>
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between writing a function and calling an existing function. You should look at an introductory JS tutorial.

Comment: do you have a database with their names? are you trying to update as they type? your question doesn't make sense

Comment: what's your purpose for writing this code? Code doesnt seems doing anything meaningful.

Comment: I'm new to coding and just playing around to try and get the hang of it, I wanted to just make a form where the user could enter their name and the code would display "Hello, +input"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select the element to want to read. `document.getElementById("firstname")` then use `.value` to get the value.
- Select the element where you want to put these values to show to user .. `document.getElementById("show")` and print the values.. `.innerText`.
- Now put the logic inside a function `showName()` and call this function on `onclick` event of submit button.

```js
function showName(e){
    var firstName= document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    document.getElementById("show").innerText = firstName+" "+lastName;        
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
        First name:
        <input type= "text" id="firstname" name="firstname"> <br> <br>
        Last name: <input type= "text" id="lastname" name="lastname"> <br> <br> <br>
        <input type = "button" onclick="showName()" value="submit">
        <span id="show"></span>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked thanks a lot, may I just ask what the "(e)" relates to in the function?

Comment: (e) is the event object, you can either pass it or not. `e` contains the information such as which element called the function, default behavior of the element on click. You can remove `e` and it will work normally.